# installing wxPerl on strawberry

Tags: perl, installation, wxwidgets, strawberry-perl, wxperl

I am trying to install wxperl on strawberry. I can't install Alien::wxWidgets. I tried everything I can think of. Usually I get an error like this one:

```
Creating library file: ..\..\src\stc\..\..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxmsw28u_stc.a
compilet.exp:fake:(.edata+0x3c): undefined reference to `boot_compilet'
compilet.exp:fake:(.edata+0x40): undefined reference to `boot_compilet'
```

I don't know what that means. I tried with wxWidgets v 2.8.12 and 2.9.3 and various options. I started with cpanm and later evoking perl Build.PL manually with all kinds of options.

I am on Windows 7 64 bit. I tried with 5.14.2 32bit and 64bit. I am pretty sure that my path has no other perl installation than the one I currently using.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Using strawberry-perl-5.16.3.1-32bit on Windows 7.

It seems that even though the build process crashes with the error message above, Alien::wxWidgets has, in fact, been successfully made, and is ready to install.

Got the same error message building Alien::wxWidgets from SVN trunk. I ran 'build test' and the tests passed so I ran 'build install'. Wx compiled successfully, all tests passed. Padre editor compiled successfully, all tests passed, and it works well.

It is also possible to install via PPM in Strawberry perl:

ppm set repository wxPerl http://www.wxperl.co.uk/repo29 (for WxWidgets-2.9.4)

ppm install Alien::wxWidgets (version 0.61)

Unfortunately, the latest version of Padre editor requires Alien::wxWidgets 0.62, so building Alien::wxWidgets from source is necessary to make Padre from CPAN.

Alternately, you can use the Citrus Perl distribution created by Mark Dootson. One caveat, the version of Perl, 5.16.1, is not the latest, but it is more recent than DWIM Perl build of Strawberry Perl 5.14.2.1 RC.

I would recommend using the latest Strawberry Perl 5.16.3, or 5.14.4.1 for security reasons because it has a a fix for the rehashing flaw which could be used for denial of service attacks. Described here:

http://www.vuxml.org/freebsd/CVE-2013-1667.html

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to install [DWIM Perl](http://dwimperl.com/), which is a Perl distribution which contains Strawberry preloaded with a whole lot of commonly used CPAN modules, and includes `Alien::wxWidgets`.